# Possible to Turn on iPhone Flash While Facetime Camera is Active?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, camera

Is it possible to turn on the flash hardware on an iPhone when the Facetime camera is active in the native app? If not, how can I go about it programmatically?

Comment: Native app meaning in the bult-in Camera app?

Comment: yes, the apple pre-loaded camera app.

Comment: No not possible within that app. You should be able to code up this functionality in an app of your own, however.